# Python code to take minute data and average it to hourly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone I am trying to create some code that averages minute data for a single month into hourly.  I am receiving an error that says "No numeric types to aggregate".  The weird thing is that this code works on some of my files and not others.

The error happens from the line `df = df.resample('1H').mean()`

**Actual Data**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8c77572an2pk8n/OCTTEST.csv?dl=0

**Here is my code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", index_col="DateTime", parse_dates=True, low_memory=False)
df = df.resample('1H').mean()
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq="1H"))
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=True, index_label="DateTime")
```

Comment: your datetime format seems a bit unusual. Does `11/1/2014 1:00` represent one minute past midnight on 11/1/2014?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input for which the code produces an error? The example given seems to pass through correctly, although the values provided are not as you'd expect (as they are parsed as hours not minutes)

Comment: thats not my actual data that was just an example.  The error occurs when I input the line df = df.resample('1H').mean()

Comment: If I run the code with the example provided, it works correctly. It's difficult to troubleshoot your error if it's not reproducible.

Comment: hmm yeah I think it has to do with some non-numeric data.  Its just weird because it runs on some of my files and not others whereas the files should have the exact same format.

Comment: What happens to times after the first hour - would you get a format such as `11/1/2014 61:00`? Or would it be `11/1/2014 1:1:00`. I'm not sure if the date parser would like either of them

Comment: oops I just realized the data I input is hourly.  The minute data would just be 0:00 for 12:00 and 0:01 for 12:01.  I edited the original question.

Comment: Your code works with the example data you've posted. Please include a sample dataset with which we can reproduce the error.

Comment: i've posted a link to my actual data in the original post.